# Python spynner and native_click

Tags: python

I start to use https://github.com/kiorky/spynner/

First sample with google

```
import spynner
import pyquery

browser = spynner.Browser(debug_level=spynner.INFO)
browser.create_webview()
browser.show()
browser.load("http://www.google.com")
browser.fill("input[name=q]", "archlinux")
browser.click("input[name=btnG]",True)
browser.click("a[class=l]:first")
```

Work only for first click on btnG, and not working on "a[class=l]:first" :(

if i use

```
browser.native_click("input[name=btnG]",True)
```

It not work

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Tried sorting out all the paths, pythonpaths and other things but gave up. Installed python 2.7 from source under my home directory, installed virtualenv and setup a new virtual environment with that python. Cloned the latest version of spynner from git and ran 'setup.py install' from within the virtual environment.

I know it's not the most elegant way... but I gave up trying to solve it the "right" way. :-)